# More than one modules implementing the hook_module_implements_alter

Tags: hooks

How can I know what module will implement earlier?

I have a module (custom) which implements *[hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7)* and an other module (contrib) which is also implements it. In this case the contrib module is being executed later, overriding my implementation.

So, how can I ensure that my module will be executed later?

Comment: Set the weight of your module in the system table to higher than the other module's? That should force _your_ implementation of `hook_module_implements_alter()` to run last. Failing that, maybe you can actually use `hook_module_implements_alter()` to push your module's implementation of `hook_module_implements_alter()` to the end...though my brain hurts after thinking about that

Comment: Nice try. But all of it could be versioned? Im using features.

Comment: The latter method wouldn't need anything extra (the hook would go in the feature module). Not sure about the first method, and Google isn't turning anything up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the weight of the modules in system table to modify their execution order.

One module that can help you in that is the [Modules Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/modules_weight), which provides an admin interface and avoids changing the SQL record directly.